# Cannot uninstall ADT plugin in eclips

Tags: android

Today i have updated my sdk tools via sdk manager.after that my java files getting error when i check that project build target list are empty.
i think sdk path also set correctly.
So try to uninstall ADT plugin for install new ADT.but i cant uninstall ADT plugin.Its Showing below "uninstalling software has encountered a problem"

what should i do for install new ADT for getting projects build targets files.
Now my all java files are getting error because of this problem.
help me...thanks

Comment: How did you try to Uninstall ?

Comment: do you try right click and fix project properties ??

Answer (score 1):

Download a fresh [Eclipse ADT zip](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), Unzip it and replace the SDK folder with your current updated SDK folder. Start the new eclipse, Select your workspace and try to update ADT if there is any update available. You will be ready to go instead of fixing all the weird issues due to old ADT plug-in.